# Compare 2 objects in eclipse in runtime (while debugging)?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, object, compare

Can I compare 2 Objects using the Eclipse - Expressions tool, am trying to debug a Java program. The max I can do is, add both the objects to Expressions and manually expand the object to compare, I wish there was like, select 2 Object (of same kind - Class, Of course) and say "Compare" and Eclipse parses both the objects and highlights all the differences..

PS: I'm not lazy to do this manually, its just that the Object I'm dealing with is very complicated, like its got 10 levels or arraylist of Objects :)

Comment: Why not add a log statement in your code.

Comment: You should [accept some answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a elegant solution but it has worked well for me in the past is to include something like gson or other json parser in your classpath. Then in the Display view type:

```
new Gson().gson.toJson(yourObject1)
```

and

```
new Gson().gson.toJson(yourObject2)
```

Then use the json ouput save it to files and use a file comparison tool.
Longwinded but with complex objects its often worth it.

Answer (score 1):

They can be as detailed or simple as you want them to be.
Using a equals expression in the Display view may tel you if two objects are the same, but if their different, it won't tell you what those differences are.
Consider using Eclipse detail formatters. They are awesome.

Eclipse's Inspect view can often be littered with unwanted data that just clutters your mind and what your really interested in. The ouput you decide to display is your choice with detail formatters.

See the link below for an idea of how to use them.

http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Eclipse/Eclipse_Detail_Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Find "Display" view under debug category. It is not open by default in the java debug perspective. You will be able to execute pretty much arbitrary java statements during the debug session.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but am still wondering how will I compare 2 object visually in Display ?

Comment: The same way you would inside java code... Say "x.equals( y )", select and hit the execute button in the view. There are two execute buttons. One will execute the statement and print the result. The other will just execute it.

Comment: hmm... what if x and y are objects of a complex class, say Employee, which has listManagers, listVehicles, mapSubordinates, mapRole, listInventoryCheckouts, strJoinDates. Now I want to visually compare each of these items inside x and y and find the difference in them :)

Comment: You can call any function you have available. If you've implemented a diff function, then you can call it. Eclipse isn't going to do a diff for you.